# Ajax change old text to new text after success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have one question about ajax change text after success.

I have crated this ajax. This code working fine. But i want to change old text to new text in `.chnged` div.

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="text" value="<?php echo $text;?>">
<input type="submit" id="change" value="Change Text">
```

the old text is = `<div class="chnged">Old text</div>`

when clicked `#change` button then = `<div class="chnged">New Text</div>`

how can i do that anyone can tell me ?

```
$('#change').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $.base_url+'change_text.php',
            data: {text:$('input[name="text"]').val()},
            beforeSend: function(){$("#posting").html('<img src="icons/ajaxloader.gif"/>'); },
            success: function(html,data) {
            $('.chnged').val('');
            swal({   title: "Success!",   text: "Thanks.",   timer: 5000 });
            }
        });
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you waiting for the document to load before you bind the click listener to the `#change` button?

Comment: Show the php output to be able to help you more

Comment: @guest271314 from `<input type="text" name="text" value="old text">` this input have old text from value. When i change this value and press submit. Then new value automatically added `.chnged` div.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the content of the `.chnged` element with jQuery like this:

```
$(".chnged").html(html);
```

In this code, I assume that the `html` variable is what you want the new value to be.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  What do you mean by "That"?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.chnged').text('New text');
```

or if it is html then

```
$('.chnged').html('<p>New text</p>');
```

Comment: The `input[name="text"]` means when you write a new value then this value is posting from database. And then the new value showing in `.chnged`but your code is only showing New text.

Comment: yes, I just gave you an example. Is the new text in `html` variable that you get back from `change-text.php`?

Comment: Show me the php output